# AWS HTTP API Gateway URL Based Routing

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

Okay so here is my requirement. I want to have end points for my customers like so:

```
https://customer-a.mydomain.com 

https://customer-b.mydomain.com
```

Now, when we access the `customer-a` endpoint above, I expect AWS to route the request to customer A's ECS Fargate service which is load balanced by `https://customer-a-elb.mydomain.com`

Similarly, when we access the `customer-b` endpoint above, I expect AWS to route the request to customer B's ECS Fargate service which is load balanced by `https://customer-b-elb.mydomain.com`

The plan was, from my DNS, I would route everyone who accesses `*.mydomain.com` (wild card DNS entry) to the same API Gateway in AWS. And let the API Gateway determine which load balancer to route to **depending on the base URL**.

I was hoping this can be easily achieved using AWS API Gateway but so far I have not been able to find a solution to implement this. From what I understand, it is only possible to do path based routing (as opposed to base URL based routing which is really what I need in this case).

Any hints would be much appreciated.

**CLARIFICATION :**
per my requirement, both the customers need to access the same path /myservice but on different ELBs. For e.g.

```
https://customer-a.mydomain.com/service1 -> https://customer-a-elb.mydomain.com/service1 
https://customer-b.mydomain.com/service1 -> https://customer-b-elb.mydomain.com/service1
```

Somehow I think path based routing cant handle this scenario - as we can define only one route for a path.

Comment: Why not do this on route53?

Comment: Because I have all my DNS records maintained elsewhere and I don't want to migrate to Route53 just for this requirement. Are you saying that is the only way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

API Gateway supports path-based routing. And you can configure which resources will receive incoming API requests based on the URL requested by the client. The following example may help you.[link](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/architecture/using-api-gateway-as-a-single-entry-point-for-web-applications-and-api-microservices/)

Comment: Well, this link while it looks great at a high level, the devil is in the details I guess. Particularly, I would like to know how to define the routes for the requirement I had stated in my post. This article assumes that customer1 accesses service1 and customer2 accesses service2 - hence defining routes is straightforward. For me, I need both customers to access the service1 but on different ELBs. I will clarify that in my post as well.